# Does 両目 have a special meaning or is it just a mistake?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, parsing, counters

Today I found this sentence on my Japanese textbook (みんなの日本語中級I - 本冊 pg. 70) And it didn't make any sense to me.

> 前から２両目の電車を降りたところで待っています。

I looked for 両目 on [電子辞書](http://jisho.org/) and it says it means both eyes. Still didn't make any sense to me so I put it in Google Translator and the result was... well the expected one:

> We are waiting in the place where I got off the train two eyes from the front.

Does this have any special meaning (I mean the use of 両目) or is it just that there is a mistake on the textbook and it should just be:

前から２目の電車を降りたところで待っています。

Which means the 2nd train.

Comment: Doesn't the textbook explain this 目 at all?  That is hard to believe.

Comment: The textbook explains what is the meaning of 目 but what it doesn't says is that 両 is the counter for train cars (as @snailplane stated). That was what confused me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you have the ordinal ２, plus the counter 両{りょう}, which is used to count the cars on a train.  The combination ２両 would mean "two [train] cars".

When you add the ordinal suffix 目{め} to ２両, it changes from "two cars" to "the second car".  So, the whole phrase 前から２両目 really means the second car from the front (of the train).

Your sentence does *not* contain the word 両目{りょうめ} meaning "both eyes".